# will a js function accept an array of objects in place of its arguements?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function with X arguments.  I was curious if functions will accept an object which contains the args and still function correctly.

Example:

```
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var z = "test";
  someFunction(x,y,z);
```

vs

```
  var obj = new Object();
  obj.x = 0;
  obj.y = 0;
  obj.Z = "test";
  somefunction(obj);
```

vs.

```
  var obj = new Array();
  obj.push(0);
  obj.push(0);
  obj.push("test");
  somefunction(obj);
```

I know you could program it to handle it, but i was curious if functions would be able to accept args in different formats as long as they were all there.

**Edit:**

I seem to get a syntax error of sorts when collecting objects together.  What do i mean?  I mean i have *somefunction* which accepts some args, including callbacks..... so when trying to write it up, and put all the args/callbackks in an Array to do **somefunction.apply(objArray)**, it errors on adding the items into the set.  The way i did it was:

```
 x = new Array();
 x = [url, 
function(){
    displayFile(url, 'image', null, ft_id, null, null, null, null, !MA.isiOS());
}, 
function(e){
    if(DEBUG) console.log('Error creating gallery thumbnail');
    alert('There was a problem creating a thumbnail');
    MA.hideMessage();
}
  ];
  newArray.push(x);
```

it seems to mess up on the x definition set up.  Does this approach not like setting up callbacks like this?

Comment: Yes, it will accept anyformat.. but your function `somefunction` should handle it.

Comment: You can pass anything as an argument, but you need to handle it accordingly..

Comment: i know that.  I wanted to know if there was a native way that allows functions to accept different formats and still handle it, as per 1 of the answers below handles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will if `obj` is the Array version, and you call it using [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```
somefunction.apply(window, obj);
```

The arguments will be passed as individuals

Comment: That should be `somefunction.apply(null, obj);` - the first parameter is used as `this` and the second parameter is the array.

Comment: @Pointy: Just caught that. Thanks. :)

Comment: so, i can build an object in such a way:
var x = {"urol", function(){...}};  and then do something like   myFunction.apply(null,x);

Comment: This depends on if the OP wants to have a set number of arguments, or loop through `arguments`

Comment: @Fallenreaper: the `.apply` method requires an Array or an array-like object, so your object would need numeric indices and an propertly set `.length` property.

Comment: @ianpgall: Unless my interpretation of the question is incorrect, OP wants to destructure an object into individual arguments in order to have the args distributed to their individual parameters, so that the behavior effectively ends up like the first code example.

Comment: @user1689607 you are correct.  Im trying to do something with any number of args and any arb function... but i cant use hardcoded elements such as the other answers

Comment: @Fallenreaper: It would be great if your second example worked, but it would require the language to have a separate syntax to disambiguate the intention. Sadly, it doesn't.

Comment: .apply is just the answer, to allow the args to be applied to the given functions

Comment: Well, you better post code to explain how to retrieve the arguments, because it's not "normal behavior".

Comment: @ianpgall: What do you mean? The members of the Array will be passed as individual arguments to the `x`, `y` and `z` formal parameters. Nothing special is required inside the function.

Comment: Yes, that's nice, as long as there are ALWAYS 3 parameters passed. The OP just specified they want to "do something with any number of args and any arb function". In that case, the function declaration would NOT be `function someFunction(x, y, z)` and would instead be `function someFunction()`, where inside, you loop through the variable `arguments` which is an array of the arguments actually applied to the function.

Comment: @ianpgall: Well yes, but that's true of any function, irrespective of how it's invoked. He's asking about the calling end, and if it is possible to call it with a collection of args instead of individuals. I'm showing him how.

Comment: @user1689607 It works, just as how i wanted it to, more or less.  The downside is that in the args, there are multiple callback functions, which is causing a js issue.  Ill post the code segment as it is relavent to the topic and maybe there is something i need to do in particular.

Comment: @Fallenreaper: Where is the `newArray` variable? And which is the Array that holds the arguments? Is it `x` or `newArray`? Is your end goal to do `myfunction.apply(this, x)` or `myfunction.apply(this, newArray)`?

Comment: @user1689607 x holds the data.  newArray is a sets of data.  Im making an async throttler, so it will loop over newArray and place x into the function

Comment: i seemed to get it working sort of, but when i call the function, the middle callback function is undefined

Comment: @Fallenreaper: Ah, I see. So it is supposed to be an Array of arrays. Not sure why the middle one would be undefined. Must be some other issue. Are the first and last args showing up?

Comment: yea, I did an alert, and it is showing the contents.  Maybe it is an issue with the function calling a variable (url) which is out of scope?  Maybe that should be stored as a string or something instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17255/discussion-between-fallenreaper-and-user1689607)

Answer (score 1):

Most JavaScript functions regard the arguments as optional, if no arguments were passed, they'll simple be set to `undefined`, so regardless of the type, your function will be called and perform its tasks to the best of its abilities. That said, you *can* anticipate, and prevent certain obvious issues:

```
function moo(a,b)
{
    console.log(a + ' & ' + b);
}
moo('cat','dog');//logs cat & dog
moo();//logs undefined & undefined
moo({name1:'catbert',name2:'dogbert'});//logs [object Object] & undefined
```

As you can see, there's a lot of cases where your function might perform badly, or not at all... To get around this, you could write your function like so:

```
function moo(a,b)
{
    if (a instanceof Array)
    {
        return moo.apply(this,a);
    }
    if (a instanceof Object)
    {
        args = [];
        for (n in a)
        {
            if (a.hasOwnProperty(n))
            {
                args.push(a[n]);
            }
        }
        return moo.apply(this,args);
    }
    a = a || 'No argument a';//set default value for falsy arguments
    b = b || 'No argument b';
    console.log(a + '&' + b);
}
```

It's a bit lengthy, but this way, your function can deal with both unexpected arguments:

```
moo({name1:'catbert',name2:'dogbert'});//logs catbert & dogbert
moo();//logs No argument a & no argument b
moo(['foo','bar']);//foo & bar
//and of course:
moo('cow','bull');//still works
```

Also remember that any *additional* arguments will be ignored, so

```
moo('cow','bull','sheep');//sheep is ignored
```

Well, in fact, you can still get to any argument that wasn't defined in the function definition:

```
function noArgs()
{
    var argumentArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    //or = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[0]);
    console.log(argumentArray);
}
noArgs(1,2,3);//logs [1,2,3]
```

Be weary, though the `arguments` object does have a length property, and enables you to access each argument like an array (`arguments[0]`), it's not an array! That's why You have to use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`. That will return an array containing all arguments passed to the function.

---

Just a side-note: it's best not to use the `new Array()` constructor call to instantiate a new array object, just use the literal notation: `[2,3,4,5]`. Likewise for objects: `{bar:'foobar'}`. 
The array constructor especially, though. Seeing as it could cause problems when you want an array that looks like `[123]` (`new Array(123)` returns an array with 123 indexes, all set to `undefined`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will accept any format.. but your function `somefunction` should handle all those formats.

Also it doesn't matter if you pass it in there or not..

```
function someFunction(a,b,c,d) {
   alert(a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d)
}

someFunction();  // alerts undefined undefined undefined undefined
someFunction({a: 'test'}, 10, 20, 30); //alerts [Object object] 10 20 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you will have to access the argument's properties by the variable name. Like so

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.x = 0;
obj.y = 0;
obj.z = "test";
somefunction(obj);

function somefunction(param) {
    param.x; //0
    param.y; //0
    param.z; //test
}
```

You can also access a functions arguments with the variable `arguments`.

```
function somefunction() {
    var param = arguments[0];
    param.x; //0
    param.y; //0
    param.z; //test
}
```

Natively, *no* you cannot. Refer to **user1689607**'s answer for a solution.

Comment: I am aiming for a generic case, that will allow a user to have any number of variables